# organize similar items in columns from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table named 'artist' with columns - `id`, `name`, `genre`

I need to find out all artist that share the same genre.

Here's an example: If artist X has genre ‘rock’ and ‘classic’, artist Y has genre ‘classic’ and ‘pop’, and artist Z has genre ‘pop’, then sample output as below:

```
first artist | second artist  | genre
X            | Y              | Classic
Y            | Z              | Pop
```

Comment: What SQL have you tried? At a quick glance, it doesn't look like your schema would work really. Would probably be better having an artist column and genre column only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Join data using Genre
2. Exclude "mirror duplicates" (XY-Classic vs YX-Classic)  and loops (
   ZZ-Pop ) using S.id < J.id condition:

   ```
   Select S.Name as FirstArtist,
   J.Name as SecondArtist,
   S.Genre as CommonGenre
   From Artist S 
   Inner Join Artist J 
   ON S.Genre = J.Genre and S.id < J.id
   ```

Comment: Edit: removed duplicates

Comment: You should always explain your answers instead of just giving code

Comment: perfect! This gives exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your sample output, you're trying to do two things. First, order your data set, and second, "pivot" it so some columns in your data become rows.

The first part:

```
  SELECT name, genre
    FROM artist
   ORDER BY genre
```

The second part is presentation.  There are many ways to do this. You could try this, for example.

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) AS names,
         genre
    FROM artist
   GROUP BY genre
   ORDER BY genre
```

Or you could look up various techniques in MySQL to do pivoting.  Hint: they're all kind of difficult.

Or, you could do this in your presentation software.

Comment: This works well. I'm new to sql, your explanation helped me understanding the script well. I'll research more on pivots for MySQL.